# How to list configured routes in Ktor

Tags: ktor

I am setting up a project with multiple modules that contain different versions of api.

To verify correct route configuration I would like to print configured routes to application log like it is done in spring framework.

Is it possible and what should I use for that?

Comment: Your question is pretty broad and may be answerable via some simple searching. Please explain why the resources that are openly available are not able to assist you.

Comment: @tisaconundrum well if we take it philosophically, the source code of this library is openly available and I would be able to resolve my problem just by reading the sources. Obviously, I spent time googling and searching for answers with no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by recursively traversing routes starting from the root all the way down the tree and filtering in only ones with the HTTP method selector. This solution is described [here](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/issues/1252#issuecomment-551304202).

```
fun Application.module() {
    // routing configuration goes here

    val root = feature(Routing)
    val allRoutes = allRoutes(root)
    val allRoutesWithMethod = allRoutes.filter { it.selector is HttpMethodRouteSelector }
    allRoutesWithMethod.forEach {
        println("route: $it")
    }
}

fun allRoutes(root: Route): List<Route> {
    return listOf(root) + root.children.flatMap { allRoutes(it) }
}
```

Please note that the code above must be placed after the routing configuration.

Comment: This is perfect. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of Ktor you can use:

```
fun Application.module() {
  val registeredRoutes = mutableListOf<Route>()
  routing {
    registeredRoutes.addAll(children)
  }
  // needed to evaluate all registered routes
  client.post("")

  // do stuff with your list of routes
}
```

To be honest it doesn't look like the nicest solution but it's working and I couldn't figure out another way.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still looking for a clean-ish solution you can grab the routing configuration using `Application::routing` function which always returns the same instance of the routing configuration.

```kotlin
fun Application.module() {
    
    val routing = routing {
        // Register your routes here
    }

    println(routing.children)
    
}
```

Or you can do it in every scope where you have access to an instance of an `Application`

```kotlin
val TestAppPlugin = createApplicationPlugin(
    name = "TestAppPlugin"
) {
    println(application.routing {}.children)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Next a solution which includes HTTP methods and path parameters:

```kotlin
/**
 * Collects all the routes defined in the application.
 *
 * @return A list of strings representing the registered routes.
 */
fun Application.collectRoutes(): List<String> {
    return routing {}.allRoutes()
}

/**
 * Recursively collects all the terminal routes from the current route and its children.
 * Terminal routes are those that directly handle requests and are not just path prefixes.
 *
 * @param prefix The prefix to be used for the path of each route.
 *               It accumulates as it goes deeper into the route tree.
 * @return A list of strings representing the terminal routes.
 */
private fun Route.allRoutes(prefix: String = ""): List<String> {
    val routes = mutableListOf<String>()

    /**
     * Checks if the route is a prefix (non-terminal) route.
     * A prefix route is identified by having children with specific HTTP method selectors.
     *
     * @return True if the route is a prefix route, false otherwise.
     */
    fun Route.isPrefixRoute(): Boolean {
        return this.children.any { it.selector is HttpMethodRouteSelector }
    }

    /**
     * Recursive function to traverse the route tree and collect terminal routes.
     *
     * @param currentPath The current path accumulated from the parent routes.
     */
    fun Route.collectRoutes(currentPath: String) {
        val pathSegment = when (val selector = this.selector) {
            is PathSegmentConstantRouteSelector -> "${currentPath}/${selector.value}"
            is PathSegmentParameterRouteSelector -> "${currentPath}/{${selector.name}}"
            is PathSegmentWildcardRouteSelector -> "${currentPath}/*"
            else -> currentPath
        }

        // Add the route if it's a terminal route (has an HttpMethodRouteSelector and is not a prefix route).
        if (this.selector is HttpMethodRouteSelector && !this.isPrefixRoute()) {
            val method = (this.selector as HttpMethodRouteSelector).method.value
            routes.add("$method $pathSegment")
        }

        // Recursively collect routes from children.
        this.children.forEach { it.collectRoutes(pathSegment) }
    }

    this.collectRoutes(prefix)

    return routes.distinct()
}
```

Usage:

```kotlin
fun Application.module() {
    val endpoints: List<String> = this.collectRoutes()
    endpoints.forEach {
        println(it)
    }
}
```

Example output, showing HTTP methods and multiple path parameters:

```
GET /v1/employees
POST /v1/employees
DELETE /v1/employees
GET /v1/employees/{employee_id}
PUT /v1/employees/{employee_id}
DELETE /v1/employees/{employee_id}
POST /v1/employees/{employee_id}/employments
DELETE /v1/employees/{employee_id}/employments/{employment_id}
```